# Insert item into sorted doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, doubly-linked-list

I am attempting to insert integers into a doubly linked list. The edge cases (front and back) work fine. Inserting between two nodes does not. The value is not inserted at all.

Here is the public piece of the Node class:

```
public:

Node* next;

Node* prev;

T data;

Node() : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}

Node(const T& dataArg) : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr), data(dataArg) {}

Node& operator=(const Node& other) {
  next = other.next;
  prev = other.prev;
  data = other.data;
  return *this;
}
~Node() {}
```

Here is my code for inserting into the linked list:

```
void LinkedList<T>::insertOrdered(const T& newData) {

     Node* newNode = new Node(newData);
     newNode->data = newData;
 

     //Check if there are no nodes 
    if (head_ == nullptr){
    head_ = newNode;
    tail_ = head_;
    size_++;
    return;
   
    }
 
    if (newNode->data < head_->data){
    newNode->next = head_;
    head_ = newNode;
    size_++;
    return;
    }
 
    if (newNode->data >= tail_->data){
    newNode->prev = tail_;
    tail_->next = newNode;
    tail_ = newNode;
    size_++;
    return;
    }
 
    Node* thru = head_;

 
    while(thru != NULL && (newNode->data >= thru->data)){
       
            thru = thru->next;
            return;
    }
     if(thru){
         newNode->next = thru;
         newNode->prev = thru->prev;
         thru->prev->next = newNode;
         thru->prev = newNode;
         size_++;
         return;
     }
  
}
```

I am running this code to test:

```
LinkedList<int> l;
l.pushBack(5);
l.pushBack(6);
l.pushBack(8);
l.pushBack(9);
std::cout << "List: " << l << std::endl;
l.insertOrdered(7);
l.insertOrdered(4);
l.insertOrdered(-1);
l.insertOrdered(10);
std::cout << "Inserting items now." << std::endl;
std::cout << "List: " << l << std::endl;
std::cout << "Expected: " << expected << std::endl;
if (l != expected) errorReaction("wrong result");
```

Here is the result:

```
Testing insertOrdered:
List: [(5)(6)(8)(9)]
Inserting items now.
List: [(-1)(4)(5)(6)(8)(9)(10)]
Expected: [(-1)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)]
```

As you can see the 7 is not added. Hoping someone can provide some guidance.

Comment: `return` within the `while` loop exits the function just after advancing once.

Comment: oh wow. I completely missed that. That did in fact fix the entire issue. Thanks!